# Rails: update_attributes not honoring dependent: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, foreign-keys, cascade

When I use update_attributes, it should be deleting certain entries and deleting their dependents (as I use dependent: :destroy). However, I am getting a foreign key error and don't know what to do differently.

I have the following

```
class StudentGoal < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :goal
    belongs_to :student
    has_many :student_goal_scores, dependent: :destroy
end

class StudentGoalScore < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student_goal
end

class Goal < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :student_goals, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :students, through: :student_goals
end
```

In the rails console, if I run the following (the goal previously had multiple students associated with it):

```
Goal.find(2).update_attributes(students: [Student.find(69)])
```

I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  
update or delete on table "student_goals" violates foreign key constraint 
"fk_rails_bcae4e177a" on table "student_goal_scores") DETAIL:  Key (id)=(49) is 
still referenced from table "student_goal_scores".
```

If I just try destroying a StudentGoal with StudentGoal.find(number).destroy, the StudentGoalScores are deleted correctly.

Is there something I can do to make update_attributes correctly cascade a delete?

Comment: you could use depedent: :destroy, prepend: true

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, as [documentation states](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

> :dependent
>
> Controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is **destroyed**

`update` shouldn't delete anything.

EDIT: Rails handles automatically join tables (like `StudentGoal`), this means you don't need to worry about deleting/updating that table when you update associated tables (`Goal.find(2).update_attributes(students: [Student.find(69)]`) **but**, in your case, you set a FK in the join table (`has_many :student_goal_scores`), and the corresponding DB constraint.

And that's the problem. Rails tries to update Goal/Student association, but DB complains because that will leave orphan `StudentGoalScore` record.

You can either move `StudentGoalScore` columns to `StudentGoal` or set a callback in `StudentGoal` to automatically delete `StudentGoalScore`.

Comment: The update_attributes currently DOES try to delete, which makes sense since I am removing some dependents (changing students from, say, students 2 and 3, to just student 2). I want this delete to cascade (a destroy). So yes, update should delete things and does. I just need it to destroy things instead, and am not sure how.